# re-checking injected fields in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have Spring controllers that use constructor injection to satisfy service layer dependencies.  Works well.  Now, there is some old code out there in the organization that double checks if the dependencies are valid.  I consider this an anti-pattern as it's code relating to cross cutting concern which the injected client shouldn't worry about.

If the dependency cannot be resolved then the IoC container (Spring) will raise the appropriate error (UnSatisfiedLink or whatever), the client using these service should be agnostic to how or if these dependencies were properly injected.. it should assume that all dependencies are initialized and ready to go.  This is the essence of using IoC in the first place.

For instance I see this:

```
  public MyController(MyService myService) {
     this.myService = myService;
  }
```

and then:

```
@PostConstruct
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
 if(myService == null) {   // unecessary in my opinion
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("MyService is not set!");
 }
}
```

These types of "double-checks" are unnecessary and result in cross cutting concern code clutter, opinions?

Comment: _"opinions?"_ This is not a matter of opinion but a fact you can easily prove or disprove (opinion-based questions have no place on SO, either way)

Answer (score -1):

I would not consider a check like this

```
if(myService == null) {
 //throw nice readable error
}
```

clutter that I would delete as part of a code review. The issue I would more see is the "throws Exception" part that you have to introduce now as part of this method. So every method calling this method now needs to implement a try/catch or re-throw implementation.

I would rather recommend an Exception that inherits from the [RunTimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

The reason for that would that this is an exception that presents a severe configuration or setup error. You don't expect this to happen as part of any kind of a regular functionality. So I would not consider any other method needs to be "informed" and has a special try/catch block to behave differently. The application should basically crash with an Exception. Right at this point. There might be some catch handlers on global service level that catch those exceptions and then, for example rollback transactions, translate the Exception in SoapError et cetera. But generally I would not consider any additional value in throwing and explicit exception that requires other calling methods now to implement a special catch block.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) The reason I thought checks in the afterPropertiesSet are unecessary is because of the following: a) The PostConstruct will never be reached as the instantiation will fail when the AutoWiring fails. By default when autowiring lookup fails Spring will thrown and UnsatisfiedDependencyException b) Null args passed to the constructor do not have a use case in the application as it's picked up via component scan and not manually wired

Comment: You might be right, but there might be cases where somebody overwrites handlers et cetera. Generally you are right. But if that is the code of another person I would not blame him for doing that as it is not necessarily wrong. I would just make sure this check does not throw Exceptions that we do not have specific functionality/requirements for.